# How is addressing done of L1/L2/L3 cpu caches vs. ram allocation?

Tags: memory, cpu, cpu-cache

As cache sizes on cpus increase, how is it managed vs. RAM?  Do considerations need to be made while making an application to ensure you're getting the most out of your Cache or is that completely at the hardware level?

Comment: short answer, no. IO Module Cache is a static mechanism, that just does the same thing, but bigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of considerations to be made when developing software in regards to cache utilization. So much so that all I can do is point at this article.

https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/software-techniques-for-shared-cache-multi-core-systems

As far as cache vs ram, a CPU cache simply stores frequently used data on the CPU which will allow quicker access to it than if it had to travel from the RAM. Check out the ars technica artical page 2 for a table on latency times. It's a great read.

http://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2002/07/caching/